# How do I find the value of the trig functions listed below?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the value of trig functions listed below? I need to express the answer in radical form.

a) tan(5π/12)
b) cos(-π/12)
c) sin(π/8)
Do I use the half angle identity to solve c? I'm confused of the others.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you're working from the standard known values, it'll take a half-angle to reach $\frac{\pi}{8}$. For the others, $\frac{5\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{-\pi}{12}=\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\pi}{4}$, so angle addition identities will do it.

These are not values I have memorized; if I needed them, I'd use the identities myself.

Comment: We can also use the half-angle formulas to obtain $\cos (5\pi/12)$ and $\sin (5\pi/12)$  from $\cos (5\pi/6)$ to answer a) and b).

Comment: Sure. I'd rather go with the rational operations of the angle addition formulas than the square roots of the half-angle formulas if I have the choice, but that's an option too.

Comment: For the answer for the first one I got 2+3 radical 3 and the second radical 2+ radical 3 over 2.

Comment: Wrong for both (a) and (b). The second fails the common-sense test that a cosine must be between $-1$ and $1$. If you want any more feedback than that, you'll have to show your work.